# How to know when two child process has resolved nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to fire a function when two `child_process` has finished. I thought of using promise as below but it seems to trigger `Promise.all` before the promises are resolved

```
let excelParserChildOnePromise = new Promise((resolveChild, rejectChild) => {
    let excelParserChildOne = fork(excelParserTool);

    excelParserChildOne.send(`${tempFilePositionOne}`);
    excelParserChildOne.on('message', (excelArray) => {
        console.log('child one resolved')
        resolveChild(excelArray);
    })
});

let excelParserChildTwoPromise = new Promise((resolveChild, rejectChild) => {
    let excelParserChildTwo = fork(excelParserTool);

    excelParserChildTwo.send(`${tempFilePositionTwo}`);
    excelParserChildTwo.on('message', (excelArray) => {
        console.log('child two resolved')
        resolveChild(excelArray)
    })
});


childPromises.push([excelParserChildOnePromise, excelParserChildTwoPromise]);

Promise.all(childPromises).then(() => {
    console.log('inside promise all');
})
```

This prints out the following

```
inside promise all
child one resolved
child two resolved
```

How do I listen to when both process finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.push()` into the array is wrong as you are pushing an array of promises which gives you an array of an array rather than just a simple array of promises and then `Promise.all()` gets the wrong type of data (it just sees an array of an array) so it doesn't wait properly on the promises:

To fix it, change this line:

```
childPromises.push([excelParserChildOnePromise, excelParserChildTwoPromise]);
```

to this:

```
childPromises.push(excelParserChildOnePromise, excelParserChildTwoPromise);
```

Comment: yea.. took me 20 minutes to realize